# Help in Understanding num.trees, mtry, and nodsize in Random forest?

Tags: r, random-forest

I am currently creating a random forest quantile regression model in R and I am looking to have a deeper understanding on of num.trees, mtry, and nodsize. I want to understand how increasing or decreasing these values can affect a model. For example, does increasing mtry overfit a model?  I am creating a grid search and looking to leverage dynamic parameters to train the ideal model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `num.trees` or the Number of Decision Trees

For `num.trees`, it is referring to the number of trees you want to build in your model. The standard is 500. Changing the number of trees typically won't change the results. However, if you were to plot the build, and it never leveled off, it would be an indicator to increase that number.

This plot is the build process, the x-axis is the trees (first tree to the last tree) and the y-axis reflects the error rate.

[image]

This plot does not quite level off, but the error rate is at the hundredths already, so more trees are unlikely to do all that much.

### `mtry` or the Number of Variable Splits

When you build a tree, `mtry` is how many variables will be included in the first split. I have two dendrograms shown next. One is `mtry = 2`; the next the next is `mtry = 3`.

#### `mtry = 2`

The first dendrogram reflects a 2-way split or `mtry = 2`. I colored one blue and one black to try to make this more obvious.

[image]

#### `mtry = 3`

This next dendrogram, representing a three-way split, has three colors, one for each `mtry`. You can see the three clusters: blue, black, and red.

[image]

#### Using `mtry` for Tuning

Using `mtry` to tune your random forest is best done through tools like the library `caret`. That library runs many different models through their native packages but adds in automatic resampling. Using `caret`, resampling with random forest models is automatically done with different `mtry` values. There are other functions out there, like `tuneRF()` that indicate some best guess `mtry` values.

### `nodesize` or Minimum Node Size

This parameter refers to the minimum number of observations to include in a terminal node. That is the bottom of the dendrogram.
I have reused the `mtry = 2` dendrogram and marked one path in red. With the argument `nodesize = 1`, there must be at least one observation that meets the following criteria:

| Variable | Requirement |
| --- | --- |
| Positive Affect | $\geq$ 0.78 |
| Positive Affect | $\geq$ 0.82 |

Since it is the same variable in this path it may see obvious, but the path to every terminal node has requirements.

You can see that if you set this `nodesize = 9` for example, but you only had 100 observations, you would probably have a really inaccurate model. It all depends on the data, though.

[image]

Comment: I've seen different descriptions of `mtry`. In the randomforest package of R, mtry is "number of predictors sampled for spliting at each node", or "number of variables randomly sampled as candidates at each split" based on the package manual. Could you explain why there's a difference (or if I misunderstand)?

Comment: These descriptions mean the same thing. `mtry` limits the number of variables that start each decision tree as the forest grows.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm still seeing a difference between those descriptions and your answer.  I thought the descriptions mean that `mtry` is the number of variables considered at each split (each node splitting), instead of the first split, where the best rule / variable of the `mtry` variables is used as the rule.

Comment: I'm a hands-on learner. How about you? [Here's a link to a script that I stripped down to just the basic code you would need to create your own dendrograms with either `randomForest` or `ranger`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VG1GEpFoA4Iw-xI1LaEKInQ-ZMm6BKjy/view?usp=sharing). I have some data that is generated in this script so that you can see how it works along with comments in the code. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your sharing the visualization code and how you explore the algorithm.  No, it was clear enough in the manuals, so I did not delve into the details myself; and with your code I insist mtry has nothing to do with the N-way split of trees (and I don't tell how those colored trees are different splits except they are colored differently.

Answer (score 4):

I appreciate @Kat's insightful [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/541587/362671) and inspiring visualizations provided.  However, I'd like to clarify that `mtry` refers to the "number of variables that are candidates for splitting at each node," rather than just the first split.  Additionally, `mtry` is not related to the number of splits in trees. At each non-terminal node, the algorithm tests all mtry variables and selects the one that yields the best split.

To substantiate this clarification, I refer to the source code by Professor Breiman, available at: [https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Ebreiman/RandomForests/)

In the subroutine of the Fortran code (snippet shown below), up to mtry variables were attempted, and the variable that gives the best split was stored. For regression, it is

```
if (crit.gt.critmax) then
    nbest=nsp
    critmax=crit
    msplit=mvar

endif
```

whereas for categorical variable, it uses the decrease in impurity as the metric.

#### subroutine: findbestsplit

```
c#  start main loop through variables to find best split
    critmax=-1.0e20
    do 20 mv=1,mtry
        k=int(mdimt*randomu())+1
        mvar=msm(k)
            if(cat(mvar).eq.1) then
c#          it's not a categorical variable:        
            rrn=pno
            rrd=pdo
            rln=0
            rld=0
            call zervr(wl,nclass)
            do j=1,nclass
                wr(j)=tclasspop(j)
            enddo
            do nsp=ndstart,ndend-1
                nc=a(mvar,nsp)
                u=win(nc)
                k=cl(nc)
                rln=rln+u*(2*wl(k)+u)
                rrn=rrn+u*(-2*wr(k)+u)
                rld=rld+u
                rrd=rrd-u
                wl(k)=wl(k)+u
                wr(k)=wr(k)-u
                if (b(mvar,nc).lt.b(mvar,a(mvar,nsp+1))) then
                    if(amin1(rrd,rld).gt.1.0e-5) then
                        crit=(rln/rld)+(rrn/rrd)
                        if (crit.gt.critmax) then
                            nbest=nsp
                            critmax=crit
                            msplit=mvar
                            
                        endif
                    endif
                endif
            enddo
            
        else
c#          it's a categorical variable:        
c#           (ignored for clarity...)
20  continue
```

#### hands-on visualization

I also attempted a practical visualization by using the iris dataset in R.  I explored single trees with varying `mtry` values, ranging from 1 (where only one variable is a candidate) to 4 (where all variables are candidates). This was done using the randomForest package and the to.dendrogram function, credited to Kat:

```
set.seed(395)
data(iris)
## Look at the third tree in the forest.
irRF <- randomForest(iris[,-5], iris[,5], ntree=10, mtry=1)
# Considered variables: Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width; target variable: Species
getTree(irRF, 3, labelVar=TRUE)
getTree(irRF, 3, labelVar=TRUE)  %>% to.dendrogram() %>% plot()
```

Here when `mtry` is 1, each node takes one randomly selected variable as the candidate, and use it for the split. You can see one varialbe can be used multiple times consecutively, but all variables may appear along the tree.
[image: With mtry = 1]

When `mtry` is 4, at each split node, all 4 variables are considered -- this results in a tree that always decides the split from from all 4 variables.  Note how you **cannot** tell `mtry` just from visualizing the tree.
[image]

### mtry and overfitting

The impact of increasing `mtry` on overfitting is context-dependent. According to the no free lunch theorem, I think the best way to identify the optimal `mtry` is through hyperparameter tuning and testing.